# Same div/menu item on page postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 div and 3 menu item in my asp page.Each menu is a  tag.On clicking anchor tag will show each div.My problem is when i am in 3rd menu item/div and when i am clicking a button there i am losing 3rd div and 1st div will come up.How can i keep the same div/menu item on post back?

```
<ul class="headr" id="form_blck">
<li><a href="#blck1">A</a></li>
<li><a href="#blck2">B</a></li>
<li><a href="#blck3">C</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="fwrapper" id="blck1">
<div class="fwrapper" id="blck2">
<div class="fwrapper" id="blck3">
```

Comment: add it into query string/hidden and based on it set the display none/block when page gets loaded. add your button click event too

Comment: @SamLeach code is exactly like above.There will be buttons in each div

Comment: @SamLeach when click A blck1 will show up,when click B blck2 will show up,when click C blck3 will show up,

Comment: That is markup. I mean JavaScript, ASP.NET views and code behind. Why are you posting back to the server to do this? Hide/Show stuff client side.

Comment: @ i have buttons in each div.On clicking the button i am doing some server side DB coding

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET WebForms use out-of-the-box feature "MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" in Page Directive

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>
```

Comment: I have only one page and it contains different tabs

Comment: MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" will maintain scroll of page not tabs, you didn't mention tabs in your question and this feature not related to MasterPage.